# How to set up networking for lxc containers in OpenStack?

Tags: networking, lxc, openstack

I am working on a setup of OpenStack using LXC containers for virtualization. I can launch instances (at least the instance log reports so). However, I can neither ping them nor connect to them via ssh and the instance log reports that the network interfaces could not be raised properly (see log below). 
No further errors are raised in the nova and neutron logs.

I tested the LXC setup locally starting the container directly on the compute node and connect to it as intended. For this purpose traffic is bridged directly to the container like [here](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Libvirt_and_bridging). 
From this observation I would conclude that all LXC-related module requirements are met (lxc-checkconfig reports so, too). 
I then extracted the image ([tutorial](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/14401/ubuntu-image-for-libvirt_typelxc/)) and provided it to OpenStack for container instantiation.

I, moreover, tried to track the packages transmitted during a ping attempt by tcpdump. They seem to reach the control node but are not relayed to the compute node (or the instance/ container). 
However, I do not get where they are actually lost and why.

*Question:*
How I can I find out where the actual problem is , i.e. if it is OpenStack or if it is the networking within the container? I have a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem here as I cannot login to the container to find out if networking there is faulty because I have network issues...

*Background:*
The OpenStack setup consists of a control node where all scheduling and network services are running and (for now) one compute node where the containers are launched. 
The setup is running under Ubuntu 16.04 with a custom built kernel (4.8) on the compute node and uses OpenStack Newton installed via devstack.

*Configuration:*
devstack configuration on the control node:

```
[[local|localrc]]

MULTI_HOST=1
RECLONE=no
PIP_UPGRADE=False

PASSWORD=ostack
ADMIN_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
SERVICE_TOKEN=$PASSWORD
MYSQL_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD

HOST_IP=192.168.0.112

DEST=/opt/stack
SERVICE_DIR=$DEST/status
DATA_DIR=$DEST/data
LOGDIR=$DEST/logs
LOGFILE=$LOGDIR/stack.sh.log
GIT_BASE=http://github.com

export ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL=False

# enable Neutron networking
disable_service n-net
enable_service q-svc q-agt q-dhcp q-l3 q-meta neutron

# Install the tempest test suite
enable_service tempest
disable_service zookeeper

# enable Heat service
enable_service heat h-api h-api-cfn h-api-cw h-eng

# KVM
LIBVIRT_TYPE=qemu

PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
PUBLIC_INTERFACE=enp4s0

# Neutron configuration
#FIXED_RANGE=10.0.0.0/24
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.0.0/24

Q_USE_SECGROUP=True
Q_FLOATING_ALLOCATION_POOL=start=192.168.0.5,end=192.168.0.99
Q_USE_PROVIDERNET_FOR_PUBLIC=True
OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE=br-ex
PUBLIC_BRIDGE=br-ex
OVS_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=public:br-ex
Q_L3_ENABLED=True
```

devstack configuration on the compute node:

```
[[local|localrc]]
HOST_IP=192.168.0.106
#
IFACE=br0
#
FLAT_INTERFACE=$IFACE
FIXED_RANGE=10.0.0.0/20
FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=256

HOST=192.168.0.112
SERVICE_HOST=$HOST
MYSQL_HOST=$HOST
RABBIT_HOST=$HOST
Q_HOST=$HOST
GLANCE_HOSTPORT=$HOST:9292

ADMIN_PASSWORD=ostack
DATABASE_PASSWORDD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
MYSQL_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

## Neutron options
PUBLIC_INTERFACE=$IFACE
ENABLED_SERVICES=n-cpu,rabbit,q-agt

# newly added
MULTI_HOST=1

DEST=/opt/stack
SERVICE_DIR=$DEST/status
DATA_DIR=$DEST/data
LOGDIR=$DEST/logs
LOGFILE=$LOGDIR/stack.sh.log
GIT_BASE=http://github.com

# nova -- LXC
LIBVIRT_TYPE=lxc

# logging
export ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL=False
```

lxc configuration on the compute node (/etc/lxc/default.conf):

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = br0
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:xx:xx:xx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I digged a bit further and finally found the actual issue: The `vxlan` kernel modules were not compiled. Adding these solved the problem.
I also removed the bridge device so that the OpenStack uses the network interface directly.

For reference -- in the case that anyone encounters the same problems, the new configuration for devstack:

control node:

```
[[local|localrc]]
MULTI_HOST=1
RECLONE=no
PIP_UPGRADE=False

PASSWORD=ostack
ADMIN_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
SERVICE_TOKEN=$PASSWORD
MYSQL_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD

HOST_IP=192.168.0.112

DEST=/opt/stack
SERVICE_DIR=$DEST/status
DATA_DIR=$DEST/data
LOGDIR=$DEST/logs
LOGFILE=$LOGDIR/stack.sh.log
GIT_BASE=http://github.com

# keep logs for n days, color them, and suppress debug output
LOGDAYS=2
LOG_COLOR=true
export ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL=False

# Neutron networking
disable_service n-net
enable_service q-svc
enable_service q-agt
enable_service q-dhcp
enable_service q-l3
enable_service q-meta
enable_service neutron

# Tempest
enable_service tempest
disable_service zookeeper

# Heat
enable_service heat h-api h-api-cfn h-api-cw h-eng

# LXC
LIBVIRT_TYPE=lxc

PUBLIC_NETWORK_GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
PUBLIC_INTERFACE=enp4s0

# Neutron configuration
FIXED_RANGE=10.0.0.0/24
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.0.0/24
Q_USE_SECGROUP=True
Q_FLOATING_ALLOCATION_POOL=start=192.168.0.5,end=192.168.0.99

# OpenVSwitch settings
Q_USE_PROVIDERNET_FOR_PUBLIC=True
OVS_PHYSICAL_BRIDGE=br-ex
PUBLIC_BRIDGE=br-ex
OVS_BRIDGE_MAPPINGS=public:br-ex
Q_L3_ENABLED=True
```

compute node:

```
[[local|localrc]]
# control node
HOST=192.168.0.112
SERVICE_HOST=$HOST
MYSQL_HOST=$HOST
RABBIT_HOST=$HOST
Q_HOST=$HOST
GLANCE_HOSTPORT=$HOST:9292

# passwords
ADMIN_PASSWORD=ostack
DATABASE_PASSWORDD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
MYSQL_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

HOST_IP=192.168.0.106

DEST=/opt/stack
SERVICE_DIR=$DEST/status
DATA_DIR=$DEST/data
LOGDIR=$DEST/logs
LOGFILE=$LOGDIR/stack.sh.log
GIT_BASE=http://github.com

IFACE=enx001e0630391d

# keep logs for n days, color them, and suppress debug output
LOGDAYS=2
LOG_COLOR=true
export ENABLE_DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL=False

ENABLED_SERVICES=n-cpu,rabbit,q-agt

# nova -- LXC
LIBVIRT_TYPE=lxc

PUBLIC_INTERFACE=$IFACE
```